# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar argumentos en vez de definir un valor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Dispongo de una serie de logs a los cuales deseo asignarles una cabecera.

Ejemplo de log:

```
barcelona,messi,10,163,73,29,etc
```

Mi cabecera necesita 3 campos, dos externos y uno incluido en la linea log.

He conseguido un script que genera la cabecera, pero he tenido que asignar los dos campos externos en el script.

Me podéis indicar cómo conseguir introducir estos dos campos externos usando argumentos.

```
# Script actual
log = sys.stdin.readline()
nombre1 = 'lionel' # Campo externo 1
nombre2 = 'andres' # Campo externo 2
nombre3 =  log.split(',')[1]
print nombre1 + ',' + nombre2 + ',' + nombre3 + '-' + log
```

Salida esperada:

```
lionel,andres,messi-barcelona,messi,10,163,73,29,etc
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Xav que quieres decir con argumentos? ¿Pasarselos al llamar al script `python myscript.py lionel andres` o mediante un input como hace con log?¿Englobar todo en una función?

Comment: Investiga el módulo [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). Es cremita...

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, lo quiero hacer como comentas "python myscript.py lionel andres".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completando la respuesta de @Patricio puedes usar como se comenta `argparse` si quieres algo más flexible y robusto. Posiblemente el ejemplo más simple sería:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()   
parser.add_argument('nombre1', help = 'Primer nombre a parsear')
parser.add_argument('nombre2', help = 'Segundo nombre a parsear')
parser.add_argument('log',     help = 'Linea de log a parsear')

args = parser.parse_args()
nombre3 =  args.log.split(',')[1]
print("{},{},{}-{}".format(args.nombre1, args.nombre2, nombre3, args.log))
```

---

Por defecto se incluye el argumento `-h` (help) que permite ver los argumentos disponibles y el uso del script (esto es modificable si queremos):

> ```
> $ python2 script.py -h
> usage: script.py [-h] nombre1 nombre2 log
>
> positional arguments:
>   nombre1     Primer nombre a parsear
>   nombre2     Segundo nombre a parsear
>   log         Linea de log a parsear
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help  show this help message and exit
> ```

---

Un ejemplo de uso correcto:

> ```
> $ python script.py lionel andres barcelona,messi,10,163,73,29,etc
> lionel,andres,messi-barcelona,messi,10,163,73,29,etc
> ```

---

Si no se agrega el número de argumentos necesarios se lanza una excepción y se imprime la guía de uso:

> ```
> $ python script.py lionel andres 
> usage: script2.py [-h] nombre1 nombre2 log
> script2.py: error: too few arguments
> ```

---

El código anterior toma la línea de log como parámetro también, si quieres usar el input basta con:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()   
parser.add_argument('nombre1', help = 'Primer nombre a parsear')
parser.add_argument('nombre2', help = 'Segundo nombre a parsear')

args = parser.parse_args()
log = sys.stdin.readline() # Se puede sustituir por log = raw_input()
nombre3 =  log.split(',')[1]
print("{},{},{}-{}".format(args.nombre1, args.nombre2, nombre3, log))
```

Esto es algo básico, hay muchas posibilidades a tu disposición usando `argparse` como argumentos opcionales, valores por defecto, casting de los parámetros, etc. Puedes mirarte la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) si lo deseas.

Comment: Muchas gracias ha sido muy útil

Answer (score 2):

La forma más sencilla de acceder a los parámetros con lo que se invoca un script es por medio de la lista [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv), de la siguiente forma:

```
import sys

for parametro in sys.argv:
  print("Parámetro: {0}:".format(parametro))
```

`sys.argv` es una lista cuyo primer ítem es el nombre del script, y eventualmente en los siguientes estarán los distintos parámetros con que invocamos el script. Por ejemplo, si corremos el ejemplo anterior así:

```
python test.py hola mundo
```

La salida será:

```
Parámetro: test.py:
Parámetro: hola:
Parámetro: mundo:
```

Para saber si se han pasado parámetros solo hay que asegurarse que `len(sys.argv)` > 1`. El acceso como te darás cuenta es posicional, es decir debes respetar el orden para que tu Script interprete cada parámetro y lo asigne a la variable adecuada. Finalmente tu script quedaría algo así:

```
log = sys.stdin.readline()

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
   print "Faltan definir parámetros"
   sys.exit(-1)

nombre1 = sys.argv[1]
nombre2 = sys.argv[2]
nombre3 = log.split(',')[1]
print nombre1 + ',' + nombre2 + ',' + nombre3 + '-' + log
```

Nota que agregué un control de la cantidad de parámetros, esto ofrece un mensaje  controlado y más legible, en caso de no usar esto ocurrirá un excepción al intentar acceder a `sys.argv[1]`.

Si requirieras un manejo más avanzado de la línea de comandos te sugiero que veas el módulo [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse)

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por la ayuda es totalmente funcional!, ampliare más con argparse.